# If HTML is not a programming language, what am I doing if I am doing HTML codes?

Tags: html

I am creating an article about programming. If I am using C#, for example, I am a C# programmer and I am *programming* using C#. How about HTML? If HTML is not a programming language, and it is a markup language, what is the correct verb applicable to a person coding in HTML? Is it just *coding*?

Comment: typically you wouldn't just be writing HTML, so possibly you'd be doing CSS and JS as well and be a 'front-end web developer'.

Comment: One usually calls that 'coding'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504719/what-is-the-difference-between-learning-html-and-learning-a-programming-language is more relevant.

Comment: Hi @hjpotter92. I have already read that post. I already know that HTML is not a *programming* language. I am asking for the correct term if someone does HTML.

Comment: HTML is not Turing complete, so its not a programming language. Its a markup language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

Wow, apparently you can call HTML/CSS a programming language because HTML5/CCS3 is [Turing-Complete](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/202489) by [by accident](http://beza1e1.tuxen.de/articles/accidentally_turing_complete.html) (for first link, check comments).

**Main Answer:**

"How about HTML?" I take the stance that to be programming, the language has to be Turing Complete. So in my definition you can't be a Regex programmer. The more lean definition is that it needs variables & control statements, as simple as having an 'if' and a 'branch' instruction. So as you point out, pure HTML is not a programming language. But HTML in the real world isn't just html text files!

I would call an HTML user a [**HTML Techonologist**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145179/1541137) or **HTML author** but if someone said they were a HTML coder or even a programmer, I wouldn't bat an eye or try to correct them. I don't think many people write plain HTML and the moment one adds Javascript or allows pages to be generated by PHP, python, or anything else it crosses the programming language definition. (**edit 2:** The moment you add CSS3 it becomes Turing Complete and thus a 'real' programming language)

**Edit 1:**

I like an answer I found about [why 'real programmers' are so defensive over reminding people HTML/CSS is not 'real programming'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28250/105946). The OP's question dealt with what to call HTML authors but this question comes up because 'real programmers' are so firm in making a distinction between their work. I like this quote from Kramli (linked before)

`There are times when the difference between programming languages and other languages really does matter. Quite often, however, we can all communicate perfectly effectively when just lump them all in together.`

Answer (score 3):

HTML is a **markup** language, hence the name HyperText Markup Language.

You are effectively the modern day equivalent of a typesetter in the print industry.

If you have minimal input in the page creation process then you're probably a Coder, however if you have significant input into page layout, then the job role is normally referred to as being a Web Designer. If you're writing lots of scripts (in say PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl or whatever your least worst option is) to produce the pages in a reasonably professional manner, then you can award yourself the wonderful title of Web Developer :-)

If you devote some thought as to how all these scripts are going to hang together, and how users are going to interact with your site, then you can claim to be an Analyst. :-)

In the Internet, job roles are quite fuzzy; personally I consider myself a mix of all of the above, concentrated more on the Developer/Analyst side as whilst I understand the technical aspects of HTML and CSS, I don't have the appreciation of good design and presentation to fully claim being a Designer in a professional context.

I also suggest you read the answers to the related questions on the right of this page...

Answer (score 3):

You have three questions...

> Q1: I am a C# programmer and I am programming using C#. How about HTML?

A1: *I am coding in HTML*

> Q2: If HTML is not a programming language, and it is a markup
>   language, what is the correct verb applicable to a person coding in
>   HTML?

A2: Verb = *Coding*, But I think you are looking for the term *Coder*

> Q3: Is it just coding?

A3: *Yes*

Answer (score 1):

As with any language - be it *musical, programmatic, mathematical,hyper text* or anything in between -  as a content creator you are a writer.

Specifically for a mark up language (such as HTML) you are annotating a document with tags that are separate entities from the text between them, and so could be considered an **Editor**, **Author**, or **Designer** because you are generally directing the content of a page.

Differences arise with **HTML** compared to writing technical documents using, for example, **DITA**. Where as a **DITA** document has its architecture and tags, it does not necessarily require a style sheet to be displayed. **HTML** on the other hand is normally consumed through a web browser so requires **CSS** transformation to be shown in a readable fashion. For this reason, formatting becomes as important as content and people writing **HTML** and **CSS** as a combination are referred to as **Web Designers**.

If you begin throwing in programming languages such as **PHP** or **JScript** you will be referred to as a **Web Developer**, but **developer** and **designer** are often interchangeable between the two options.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the correct verb applicable to a person coding in HTML?

***coding*** is a process that involves using programming language. since HTML is not a programming language you can use ***writing*** instead of ***coding***. as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML is not a programming language. The "M" stands for "Markup". Generally, a programming language allows you to describe some sort of process of doing something, whereas HTML is a way of adding context and structure to text.

If you're looking to add more alphabet soup to your CV, don't classify them at all. Just put them in a big pile called "Technologies" or whatever you like. Remember, however, that anything you list is fair game for a question.

HTML is so common that I'd expect almost any technology person to already know it (although not stuff like CSS and so on), so you might consider not listing every initialism you've ever come across. I tend to regard CVs listing too many things as suspicious, so I ask more questions to weed out the stuff that shouldn't be listed. :)

However, if your HTML experience includes serious web design stuff including Ajax, JavaScript, and so on, you might talk about those in your "Experience" section.